# Query Postgresql database to validate words order

Tags: sql, postgresql, regex-lookarounds

Suppose you have a string such as 'The quick brown dog jumped over the lazy fox' in a column. How can I query if two words are present in the string, but in specific order?

For instance, if I want to retrieve all records that include `fox` and `dog` in that specific order. If we have the following strings, we just should get just the second record, not the first record:

```
The quick brown dog jumped over the lazy fox (should not be retrieved)
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog (retrieved due to order)
```

A regular query does not keep the order of searching for `fox` first and then for `dog`:

```
SELECT d.text
from docs d
where lower(d.text) ~ '\yfox\y' and
      lower(d.text) ~ '\ydog\y'
```

How can I keep the precedence in the queried words? I was considering to use lookahead or lookbehind, but the word can be several words apart from each other.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
where d.text ~* '\yfox\y.*\ydog\y'
```

**Details**

- `\yfox\y` - a whole word `fox` (`\y` is an equivalent of `\b` in PCRE and most common NFA regex engines, you may use it in many online regex testers)
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars as many as possible
- `\ydog\y` - a whole word `dog`.

The [`~*` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE) enables case insensitive matching.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `like` if you don't care about word boundaries:

```
where d.text like '%fox%dog%'
```

or with regular expressions:

```
where d.text *~ '\yfox(\y.*\y|\y)dog\y'
```